# How can I remove two across straight line in a scatter plot graph?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macbook

[image]

so I connected dots on the scatter graph but I got the two across lines in the middle. How can I remove them? I'm using Mac version. Thanks

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your data has some errorneous points.  The red one has 0,100 possibly at the beginning or at the end.  The purple one has 0,0.  Just remove one of those points from the red and purple datasets and your graph should be OK.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the error and now it's fine.